# Parse JSON from mixed array with Decodable Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
JSON link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shimuldn/Todoey/master/file.json
```

JSON code

```
{
"report": [
     [
        {
           "name": "Delhi"
         },
        63,
        7
      ]
   ]
}
```

my code

```
struct ApiData: Codable {
    let report: [[Details]]
}
struct Details: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

I want to access the value 
decodeData.report[0][0].name

As soon as i run the code

```
debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil
```

When i remove

```
let name: String
```

There is no error.

I want to get the value from the key "name" and value 63

Comment: You don't have an array of Details you have a mixed array so it is `let report: [[Any]]` which isn't something you can use with Codable unless maybe with a custom init(from:). Is it your json, can you change the format?

Comment: What should be that `63` in your `Details` structure? What about `7`?

Comment: @joakim-danielson i can't change the JSON. the link is just a copy. What is the good way i can use?

Comment: "If i can get the value 63 i can get value 7 also." Not using the exact same technique (it depends on the nature of the data). Will it be precisely two values here, or is the object followed by a list of values? Is there precisely one array within the report array, or are there many? Basically, what do you want your `Details` struct to look like? The one you've given here just has name? And how many `Details` structs do you expect?

Comment: It is possible to get literally `decodeData.report[0][0].name` for arbitrary JSON, but the code is much more complex and harder to use than building a decoder that works for a known structure of data.

Comment: there is many more inside "report". All are the same format. I want to access decodeData.report[0][0/5 or 10 what i need].name. There is some more bellow "name": "Delhi".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'm assuming this is the data structure you want. If it's not, please update the question with your expected output data structure. (`report[0][0].name` is fragile and awkward to use in Swift. Create a struct that matches the data you would like to have. Then decode into that struct.)

```
struct ApiData: Decodable {
    let report: [Details]
}

struct Details {
    let name: String
    let value1: Int
    let value2: Int
}
```

So each Details has exactly a name object and two integer values. And a report is a list of Details.

given that, you can hand-decode Details using a `unkeyedContainer`. To get the name field out, it is handy to make a helper struct:

```
extension Details: Decodable {
    struct NameField: Decodable {
        let name: String
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        self.name = try container.decode(NameField.self).name
        self.value1 = try container.decode(Int.self)
        self.value2 = try container.decode(Int.self)
    }
}
```

Your comment notes "there is some more below name." In that case, you may want an object rather than a string here. In that case, it would look like this:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

struct Details {
    let person: Person
    let value1: Int
    let value2: Int
}

extension Details: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        self.person = try container.decode(Person.self)
        self.value1 = try container.decode(Int.self)
        self.value2 = try container.decode(Int.self)
    }
}
```

---

Finally, it's possible that the list of values is unbounded, and you want an array:

```
struct Details {
    let person: Person
    let values: [Int]
}
```

In that case you'd decode by extracting all the values out of the `unkeyedContainer`:

```
extension Details: Decodable {    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        self.person = try container.decode(Person.self)
        var values: [Int] = []
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            values.append(try container.decode(Int.self))
        }
        self.values = values
    }
}
```

There are lots of ways to approach this. It all depends on how you want to use the data, and how much structure the data has.